# Signal processing or algorithmic programming for a PLC

Tags: plc

I have an application that takes voltages and temperatures as analog inputs and does some processing using an algorithm which involves signal processing such as low-pass filtering, 
exponential smoothing, and other steps which might typically be done in a high-level programming language such as C or C++.

I'm curious how I could perform these same steps using a PLC, and in particular, the Allen-Bradley Control-Logix system?  It seems to me that the instruction set with ladder logic is too limited for this.   Could I perform this using structured text?

Comment: It may leave something to be desired, but RSLogix supports Visual Basic scripting. I have zero experience with it, but there might be something there which is better than PLC coding.

Comment: @BenMordecai: You can run VisualBasic *in* RSLogix?   I'm stunned.  I used to work for Rockwell Automation as consulting scientist in their advanced development lab, and an idea like that would never have come up.  Are  you sure?  And why would anybody want to do that?

Comment: @IraBaxter looking at it again, this is present in RSLogix 500, but not 5000. So my comment is not applicable to someone using a Control Logix. I don't know why anyone would want to run Visual Basic in general, much less to handle macros in older Windows software.

Comment: I can imagine that one would want to run VB to support the development IDE; Rockwell's dev tools on PC go back to the late 80s.   But not in a factory floor controller; what could it possibly do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ladder logic can do the computation just fine, although it isn't the nicest programming language in the world.  It has a full complement of conditionals, arithmetic, arrays, etc.

Your real problem is fitting your computation into the cyclic execution model that most ladder logic engines (and Control Logix) run:  a repeated execution of the program in the control from top to bottom, with each rung or computation being executed just once per scan.

If you need to loop over a set of values repeatedly before producing a result, you will likely have difficulty resolving the ladder engines' desire to execute everything "just once" per scan, and your need to execute a loop to produce a result.   I believe in fact that there are FOR loop operators that can repeat a block of ladder code just as conventional loop; you need to ensure that the amount of time spent in your loops/algorithm don't materially affect the scan rate.

What may work well is for you to let the the scan rate act as one of your loops; typically you compute a filter by accepting a new value into an array and then computing a result over that array.  Since you basically can't accept values faster than one-per-scan-cycle anyway, you can compute  at-most-one-filter-result per scan cycle without losing any precision.   If your array is of modest size (e.g., 10 values), you can in effect simply code a polynomial over the array as an equation to produce your filter result, and then code that polynomial (klunkily but straightforwardly) as ladder logic.

Comment: I'm new to PLC programming and thanks for the suggestions. I'm sure it will be a great help.

Comment: This https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter has a basic Structured Text implementation example if you keep scrolling down. This breaks down the math into steps simple enough that you should be able to duplicate using RSLogix Instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Control Logix PLCs do not have to execute on a cyclic sweep. I don't have RSLogix 5000 in front of me right now, but when defining the project, you are required to create one Program that executes on a cyclic sweep. But you can create other programs that do not. You can also run them off a trigger (not useful for regular input scanning) or off a fixed timer (very useful for input scanning). Keep in mind that there is no point in setting the input scan timer faster than your instrumentation updates-modern PLCs can frequently execute a scan much faster than a meter can update the data.

One good technique I have used for this is to create a program called one-second or something similar. This program will scan all your inputs, and perform all your signal processing, and then write to buffered memory locations. The rest of your program looks at those buffered memory locations, and never monitors the inputs directly. You can set the input-buffering program to execute as fast as needed for your process, up to whatever the PLC can handle before it faults.

It would also be a good idea to write your signal processing functions them selves as Add On Instructions, and then call them, with whatever parameters you need.

So you could have an AOI with a call interface like this:

```
input-1_buffered := input_smooth (low_pass, input-1);
```

This would call your input_smooth function, using input-1 as the value and input-1_buffered as the final location. low_pass would be used within the input_smooth function to jump to the appropriate logic.

Then you can write your actual smoothing logic in structured text, without anyone needing to understand it, because it will only exist in that one AOI.